# No option to restore system

Tags: time-machine, backup, macos, restore

I recently setup my Time Machine so I can easily restore my system if I break it.

Problem is that when I start the installer from my USB-drive the option "Restore from a Time Machine Backup" is not present.

The USB-drive I'm booting from have the Yosemite installer on it. I've also tried to hold in CMD+R during boot but it doesn't seem to work, I just get to the normal login screen.

Here's a bad image of what it looks like in the "Utilities"-menu.

[image: Utilities menu]

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

If this is what I believe you are asking:

At the top of you OS, you will see a clock with an arrow going round clockwise. Click that, then choose the third option down - 'Enter Time Machine'. Find your backup needed, then press restore.

Nick

Comment: Nope, not at all sorry! Before on Mavericks I could boot from the install USB-stick and then choose "Restore from a Time Machine Backup". But now that option isn't present.